# Compare Time with value

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, compare

I have a values from Tkinter Spinbox

```
       e1 = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=23, width= 3, state = 'readonly')
       e2 = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=59, width= 3, state = 'readonly')
       e3 = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=23, width= 3, state = 'readonly')
       e4 = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=59, width= 3, state = 'readonly')
```

Which I'm taking from `spinbox` to variables through `insrt()` function's `return` with this code

```
        time_func = insrt() #takes variables from Tkinter out

        first = time_func[0]
        first = int(first)
        second = time_func[1]
        second = int(second)
        third = time_func[2]
        third = int(third)
        fourth = time_func[3]
        fourth = int(fourth)
```

And inserting it to variable `morning` which is `time` function

```
        morning = time.strftime("%d:%d" %(first, second))
        evening = time.strftime("%d:%d" %(third, fourth))
```

But It returns something like this: "3:5"(3 hours and 5 minutes)

And I want to compare it with `time.time(now)` I don't want to use `datetime` because I want to compare it in defined days and `datetime` doesn't work with it well

```
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime(time.time()))
```

I'm using `time_in_range` function for compare it

```py
def time_in_range(morning, evening, x):
    if morning <= evening:
        return morning <= x <= evening
    else:
        return morning <= x or x <= evening
timerange = time_in_range(morning, evening, now)
```

Which should return True if same or False if not. 
But there is a little problem that `morning` is like this `3:5` and `now` variable is something like this `03:05` so it doesn't match at all, because of that zeros, what could I do to compere it right? Here is the full code

```py
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from datetime import date


# Function for Tkinter to associate variables
def insrt():
    element_1 = e1.get()
    element_2 = e2.get()
    element_3 = e3.get()
    element_4 = e4.get()

    return (element_1, element_2, element_3, element_4)

# Function for closing Tkinter window with button
def close_window ():
    window.destroy()

# Creating Tkinter first window and lines and labels
window = Tk()
window.title("監視システム")
Label(window, text=" スタート時間（時）").grid(row=2)
Label(window, text=" スタート時間（分）").grid(row=3)
Label(window, text=" 終わりの時間（時）").grid(row=4)
Label(window, text=" 終わりの時間（分）").grid(row=5)

e1 = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=23, width= 3, state = 'readonly')
e2 = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=59, width= 3, state = 'readonly')
e3 = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=23, width= 3, state = 'readonly')
e4 = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=59, width= 3, state = 'readonly')

e1.insert(2,"")
e2.insert(2,"")
e3.insert(2,"")
e4.insert(2,"")

e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
e3.grid(row=4, column=1)
e4.grid(row=5, column=1)


# Tkinter buttons
Button(window, text='  スタート  ', command=window.quit).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)
Button(window, text = " 閉じる ", command = close_window).grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop() # End of first Tkinter window


#setting used variables for main function
time_func = insrt() # Calling for the function (associated vars)
first = time_func[0] #Taking first number from time_func
first = int(first) #converting for the strftime
second = time_func[1]
second = int(second)
third = time_func[2]
third = int(third)
fourth = time_func[3]
fourth = int(fourth)
fifth = time_func[4]
six = time_func[5]
six = int(six)


now = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime(time.time())) # time now
morning = time.strftime("%d:%d" %(first, second)) # start time for the time function(inserting value)
evening = time.strftime("%d:%d" %(third, fourth)) # end time for the time function(inserting value)

def time_in_range(morning, evening, x):
    if morning <= evening:
        return morning <= x <= evening
    else:
        return morning <= x or x <= evening


while True:
    timerange = time_in_range(morning, evening, now)
    if timerange != True:
        print("Waiting for the right time")
        sleep(200)
    else:
        print("do something else")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easier to compare with `datetime` module. All you need is to get the current time by `datetime.now()` and then construct your morning/evening time by replacing.

```
def compare_time():
    ...
    now = datetime.now()
    morning = now.replace(hour=int(first),minute=int(second))
    evening = now.replace(hour=int(third), minute=int(fourth))
```

Then you can directly compare between all 3.

Also, your code can be vastly shortened if you choose a OOP approach:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *

class MyGui(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("監視システム")
        self.boxes = []
        labels = (" スタート時間（時）"," スタート時間（分）",
                  " 終わりの時間（時）"," 終わりの時間（分）")

        for num, label in enumerate(labels,2):
            s = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=23 if not num%2 else 59, width=3, state='readonly')
            Label(self,text=label).grid(row=num)
            s.grid(row=num,column=1)
            self.boxes.append(s)

        # Tkinter buttons
        Button(self, text='  Start  ', command=self.compare_time).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4) #スタート
        Button(self, text=" 閉じる ", command=self.destroy).grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)

    def compare_time(self):
        first, second, third, fourth = [i.get() for i in self.boxes]
        now = datetime.now()
        morning = now.replace(hour=int(first),minute=int(second))
        evening = now.replace(hour=int(third), minute=int(fourth))
        print (f"Current time: {now}, Morning time: {morning}, Evening time: {evening}")
        # do the rest of your time_in_range stuff here

root = MyGui()

root.mainloop()
```